# How i can redirect to a page php inside a server method?

Tags: php, nusoap

I have write a method in nusoap server that redirect a user to a page. I use the  "header("Location:index.php") "but doesnt work. I am getting an error like :

> Undefined index: scheme in C:......\lib\nusoap.php on line 2287

Comment: see: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php. Try `header("Location: /index.php");`

Comment: Please specify proper path for index.php.It is in same directory?

Comment: Thanks, it works..

Comment: yes, it's in same directory.@Shivani